# "Your profile can not be used because it is from a newer version of Google Chrome" error after downgrading

Tags: google-chrome

I've downloaded version 37.0 of Google Chrome but a few plugins and extensions don't work.
I've uninstalled that version and installed 35.0 again, but now I have encountered error messages.

Every time I start Chrome, I get these error messages:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix that, or at least hide those messages?

Comment: You will need to delete your Chrome profile, located in your user profile directory, to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall Google Chrome and go to **C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google** folder and delete the chrome folder, Clean the registry using CCleaner and install again the version you want.

Comment: Upvote. I was just about to say:). In addition, worth backing your bookmarks just to be on the safe side. If problem still continues then there may be some registry settings that need to be deleted as well.